# Array of data empty only on Safari - React + Redux

Tags: reactjs, safari, redux

I have an app that makes a request to fetch some data and then renders a table with that data.

The problem is that this console.log on the render method:

```
  ......
  <TableBody>
  {this.showSpinner()}
  {console.log(data)}
  {data.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map( (n, index) => {
  ......
```

gets empty on safari, but not on Firefox.. look at the pictures bellow:

Safari:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

This is resulting on a empty table (obviously) in Safari.. Sorry about the English and thank you very much.

Comment: What about response from the server? Is it ok?

Comment: Yes! the data is actually on the state, I'm current checking if the date filters that are been setting when the component mounts are behaving differently on Safari.

Comment: Bingo! is the date filter

Comment: @WolganEns Can you further explain the fix? We're seeing a difference between safari and all other browsers as well, but I don't understand what you mean by "is the date filter"